# How can I buy USD or convert INR to USD, having INR in my bank account and end up having USD in my bank account?

Tags: india, banking, foreign-exchange, money-transfer, international-transfer

I have INR (Indian Rupees) in my bank account and I wish to convert INR to USD and keep my money in USD in my bank account so that I can transfer amount in USD to US account to avoid more commission rates as in other exchanges.

Can this be possible that I wish to convert some amount of INR to USD and keep USD in my bank account?

I am kind of new to these and If yes, please help me out.

Comment: Ask your bank to exchange currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this be possible that I wish to convert some amount of INR to USD and keep USD in my bank account?

This is not possible the way you have described.

A resident Indian can hold a Foreign Currency account designated in USD.

The deposit into this accounts are only due to specified transactions. One cannot directly convert INR to USD. Read the [RBI guideline here](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/FAQView.aspx?Id=69#Q4). A simplified info is also available on [ICICI Bank site](https://www.icicibank.com/Personal-Banking/account-deposit/resident-foreign-currency-domestic-account/eligibility.page).

Answer (score 3):

You should ask your bank about currency exchange. Some banks provide that as a service, others will refer you to bigger banks. As for keeping the converted USD in your bank account, that will also depend on your bank - smaller banks probably can't, while big banks probably can.

Bottom line, you should ask your bank about it.